# How to move UIButton into a keypad when user start typing

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, keypad

I have a UIButton at bottom of the screen and when the user types in UITextView i want that button to get attached to the keypad like the screenshot I have attached. Please give some sample codes.

Design[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your question, You just need to add your button to textfield inputAccessoryView.

```
yourTextField.inputAccessoryView = confirmButton
```

To handle your original Button position, Create temporary a Button same as your Original including method name.

```
  let tempButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 30))
    tempButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    tempButton.setTitle("YourConfirmButton", for: .normal)
    tempButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    tempButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.onTapConfirmButton), for: .touchUpInside)
    yourTextField.inputAccessoryView = tempButton
```

Comment: How to make the button in the same position as in the first design when we dismiss the keyboard?

Comment: @Adbul Hoque Nuri

Comment: @JOhnMic Check updated answer.

Comment: so you are saying that if i dismiss my keyboard automatically button will come into same place?

Comment: Your original button wil not displace. You just need to create clone of your original one for display above keyboard.